# Analysing twitter for research : moving from small data to big

Tags: python, csv, twitter, bigdata, nltk

We have a research work that we are doing as part of our college project in which we need to analyse twitter data.

We have already built the prototype for classification and analysis using pandas and nltk, reading the comments from a csv file and then processing it. The problem now is that we want to scale it so as to read and analyse some big comments file also. But the problem is that we dont have anybody who could guide us(majority of them being from biology background) with what technologies to use for this massive amount.

Our issues are :-

1.] How to store a massive comments file(5 gb, **offline data**). Till now we had only 5000-10000 line of comments which we processed using pandas. But how do we store and process such a huge file. Which database to use for it.

2.] Also since we plan to use nltk, machine learning on this data, what should be our approach on parallels of ::  **csv->pandas,nltk,machine learning->model->prediction**. That is, where in this path we need changes and with what technologies should we replace them to handle the huge data.

Comment: Whilst it seems like you have the basis for a pretty interesting question, as it stands I feel it's a bit unfinished for SO. If you could do some more research, give a better basis for us to answer questions on then I'm sure you'll attract some better answers. Also, you are at risk of crossing the boundaries of asking for specific libraries or tools, which is looked down upon and is a valid reason for question closure. My advice: take a few more days to research and then come back with some more specific questions. (Python comes with SQLite which is a good database)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there's two types of scaling:

- Scale **up**
- Scale **out**

**Scale up**, most of the time, means taking what you already have, and run it on a bigger machine (more CPU, RAM, disk throughput).

**Scale out** generally means partitioning your problem, and handling parts on separate threads/processes/machines.

Scaling up is much easier: keep the code you already have and run it on a big machine (possibly on Amazon EC2 or Rackspace, if you don't have one available).

If scaling up is not enough, you will need to scale out. Start by identifying what parts of your problem can be partitioned. Since you're processing twitter comments, there's a good chance you can simply partition your file into multiple ones, and train N independent models.

Since you're just processing text data, there isn't a big advantage to using a database over plain text files (for storing the input data, at least). Simply split your file into multiple files and distribute each one to a different processing unit.

Depending on the specific machine learning techniques you're using, it may be easy to merge the independent models into a single one, but it will likely require expert knowledge.

If you're using K-nearest-neighbors, for example, it's trivial to join the independent models

Comment: Actually the commenst data has user locale, age, location,sex etc. So I'd also need to categorise comments based on say-user sex/country/locale etc. So querying a huge comments file would require me to save it in some database which would be able to handle queries for such an "unstructured file". Pandas is doing good till date. But I need a better database to query huge "unstructured file". Thats where also I need your sugestion.Thanks